# Not getting the bullet shape in my efficient frontier

Tags: python, pandas, portfolio

I'm trying to replicate the efficient portfolio from this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/python-markowitz-optimization-b5e1623060f5). As far as I can tell, I have copied his code exactly, but I am receiving different values for expected return and volatility. His returns range from .02 to .27 while mine range from -1.67 to 1.5. Does anyone have a clue what might be going on here?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np  

aapl = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'Adj. Close' : [53.06, 53.35, 53.94, 54.5, 54.42]
})
cisco = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'Adj. Close' : [15.75, 16.06, 16, 15.94, 16.04]
})
ibm = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'Adj. Close' : [160.83, 160.17, 159.41, 157.58, 156.76]
})
amzn = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'Adj. Close' : [179.03, 177.51, 177.61, 182.61, 178.56]
})

stocks = pd.concat([aapl, cisco, ibm, amzn], axis=1)
stocks.columns = ['aapl', 'cisco', 'ibm', 'amzn']
log_ret = np.log(stocks/stocks.shift(1))

np.random.seed(42)
num_ports = 6000
all_weights = np.zeros((num_ports, len(stocks.columns)))
ret_arr = np.zeros(num_ports)
vol_arr = np.zeros(num_ports)
sharpe_arr = np.zeros(num_ports)

for x in range(num_ports):

    weights = np.array(np.random.random(4))
    weights = weights/np.sum(weights)

    all_weights[x,:] = weights

    ret_arr[x] = np.sum( (log_ret.mean() * weights * 252))
    vol_arr[x] = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(log_ret.cov()*252, weights)))
    sharpe_arr[x] = ret_arr[x]/vol_arr[x]

print(all_weights[5451,:])
print('log_ret: {}'.format(log_ret.mean() * 252))
print('Return: {}'.format(ret_arr[5451]))
print('Volatility: {}'.format(vol_arr[5451]))

max_sr_ret = ret_arr[sharpe_arr.argmax()]
max_sr_vol = vol_arr[sharpe_arr.argmax()]

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.scatter(vol_arr, ret_arr, c=sharpe_arr, cmap='viridis')
plt.colorbar(label='Sharpe Ratio')
plt.xlabel('Volatility')
plt.ylabel('Return')
plt.scatter(max_sr_vol, max_sr_ret, c='red', s=50)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You cant compare your results with his as you're using only small sample (head) of his data

Comment: I ran exactly the code you copied and I have the volatility between .02 to .27

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Thank you for pointing this out. I did not consider he might be using a larger dataset.

Comment: the question text only raises an issue with the range of the portfolio moments. How about the question in the title? it is completely separate. could you post an image of the "bullet-shaped" feasible set you are having a problem with, if you even are